# API Signature Verification Failed with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to use Ruby to retrieve my balance data from a cryptocurrency exchange such as Phemex. For some reason I keep getting a response stating that the API Signature Verification failed. I've confirmed that the API_KEY and API_SECRET are correct because I've connected my Phemex account to another platform using the same key/secret and noticed that the balance data pulled successfully. I think I'm making a mistake somewhere in my get_signature or get_account_balance method that is either getting an incorrect signature or not executing the request correctly.

Here is the code I have so far

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'
require 'openssl'
require 'uri'

class PhemexBot
  API_KEY = 'mykeygoeshere'
  API_SECRET = 'mysecretgoeshere'
  BASE_URL = 'https://api.phemex.com'

  def initialize
    @api_key = API_KEY
    @api_secret = API_SECRET
    @base_url = BASE_URL
  end

  def get_account_balance(symbol)
    path = "/spot/wallets"
    uri = URI.join(@base_url, path)
    puts uri.to_s #debugging output
    timestamp = (Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i
    signature = generate_signature('GET', path, timestamp)
    puts signature #debugging output
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-phemex-access-token': @api_key,
      'x-phemex-request-expiry': timestamp,
      'x-phemex-request-signature': signature
    }
  begin
    response = RestClient.get(uri.to_s, headers)
    puts response.body
    assets = JSON.parse(response.body)['data']
    puts assets #debugging output
  rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => e
    puts "Error: #{e.response}"
  rescue JSON::ParserError => e
    puts "Error parsing JSON: #{e.message}"
  end

  if assets.nil?
    puts "No assets data found in the response"
    return 0
  end

  balance = assets.find { |assets| assets['currency'] == symbol }
  balance ? balance['availableBalance'] : 0

end

def generate_signature(method, path, timestamp)
  payload = "#{method}#{path}#{timestamp}"
  signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('SHA256', @api_secret, payload)
end

end
puts "Please input the desired symbol to retrieve balance: "
symbol = gets.chomp.to_s
bot = PhemexBot.new
eth_balance = bot.get_account_balance(symbol)
puts "#{symbol} Balance: #{eth_balance}"
```

TIA for any assistance with this. I've pulled data from google sheets in the past using an API without issue, but this one is a little over my head.

Comment: HTTP Verb does not appear to be anticipated as part of the signature. From the Docs: "x-phemex-request-signature : This is HMAC SHA256 signature of the http request. Secret is API Secret, its formula is : **HMacSha256(URL Path + QueryString + Expiry + body)**". In this case I guess I would try with `payload = "#{path}#{timestamp}"`? phemex has also provided code samples (https://phemex-docs.github.io/#code-samples) while none of them are written in ruby, if you understand any of those other languages it should be fairly straight forward to port them.